# Wordpress Avada Theme Remove Bullet Point Menu Appearing With No Reason

Tags: wordpress, fusion

Wordpress, using Avada theme with Fusion Builder. There are these bullet points appearing on the left of the homepage, when I inspect element it shows me the following:

"fusion-main-menu fusion-sticky-menu" 
"Main Menu Sticky"
"fusion-mobile-menu"

Tried to edit on WP under these categories but still can't fix it.
Any way of fixing it so this menu dissapears?
Either CSS either from WP Settings?

Website is https://dev1.bachelona.com/
so you can see what I'm talking about on the page.
A million thanks xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply following CSS to fix the issue:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```